# Android ListView drag & drop: issue adapting TouchInterceptor

Tags: android, listview

One of the requirements of the application I am currently working requires that the `ListView` should support drag and drop of child views. I am using the [TouchInterceptor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java) class from the Android Music app as reference, and while I have managed to adapt this to my app needs there is one issue which I am still struggling to resolve. Would really appreciate some comments from anyone who has used/adapted the `TouchInterceptor` class and has experience/knowledge of how the ListView works in conjunction with the adapter.

My `ListView` has circular edges  at the top and bottom and also can have different color for each row depending on the type of data that row contains. This means that my adapter `getView()` method supplies the appropriate background resource for that view. Also, for the first and last rows, I supply the background resource that have the curved top and bottom edges.

Now, anyone familiar with the `TouchInterceptor` row expansion mechanism (`doExpand()` method) would know that when a row is dragged out, it's height is set to 1 and the row below that is expanded to give an illusion that space is being made for a new item. My problem is that when the first item (which has a curved edge) is moved below, the expansion logic causes its height to become 1 so that it becomes invisible and the next item becomes the first one (or appears to be the first one.) In this case, I would now like to supply the correct background resource for this item from the adapter. In terms of logic  I was trying to do this is roughly in the `getView()` method of the adapter:

```
//do the row inflation logic and data setting
;
;
;

if ( position == 1 && mListView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()==1) {
    //set background resource with curved top edge
}
```

However `getHeight()` never returns 1. It always seems to return 0. Is anyone able to point out if calling `getChildAt()` and `getHeight` from the `getView()` method of adapter is valid? Anyone familiar with the ListView and TouchInterceptor class could plese provide any guidance on when `getView()`is exactly called by the `ListView` in the context of above and what would be a good way to set the correct background resource?